# How to store a Class variable, then call static methods of that class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, static-methods

So I want a class to be able to store a "Class" object, then later call the static methods of that class...

Basically I have multiple classes that inherit a single class, so they all have the same static methods (but return different things). I want to be able to store which subclass I am using so I know which one to call the static methods of...

I know I can get the class with

```
Class something = [VirginMobile class];
```

But I can't then do something like  `int i = [something staticMethodReturningInt];`

Is there any way I can do this?

Cheers

Comment: you can call class method using `[something staticMethodReturningInt]`. what is the type of staticMethodReturningInt ? is it class method or instance method ?

Comment: Can you show the definition of `staticMethodReturningInt`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you probably don’t want to hear that, but once you start being too clever with classes it’s a sure sign to use regular objects instead. I’m not sure if I understand your question correctly, but one way to solve issues with typing is to cast the receiver to `id`:

```
id something = [VirginMobile class];
int i = [something methodReturningInt];
```

This will compile fine, as long as the compiler can see the definition of `methodReturningInt`. And of course, at runtime `VirginMobile` has to respond to `+methodReturningInt`.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks! Can you explain why id works for this but not class though? I don't understand this...

Comment: When you’re using the `id` type (“an object”) for something, you’re effectively using dynamic typing. The compiler will be happy sending any existing message to the object and if the receiver doesn’t respond to it, you’ll only get an error during runtime. On the other hand the `Class` type is much more precise and has no method for `+methodReturningInt`, therefore the compiler objects. I’m sorry I can’t explain this better, as I’m not entirely clear on the matter myself. The [Objective-C Programming Language](http://goo.gl/Xj4bu) book by Apple should help.

Comment: Actually, that makes complete sense now that I think about it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks.  Your explanation makes sense. I'm doing this because I want a set of subclasses that have all instance methods.  Since they all return largely static content (labels and help text based on state), it seems like a waste to do all the memory management that comes with instances.